# How to draw a Non Deterministic Buchi Automaton (NBA) from the given property?

Tags: linear-temporal-logic, buchi-automata

I'm new to LTL and Buchi automaton, and I have a hard time in constructing NBA from the given formula or the property. Could somebody please help me?

The following property is given, P= "Whenever process 1 is in its waiting location (w1), it will eventually enter its critical section (c1).” where AP = {w1, c1}. I have to depict an NBA for P and complement of P.

I believe that the above property, P, can be written as

> w1 -> F(c1)

and the complement of P can be written as

> ~w1 -> G ~c1

where F represents **eventually**, G represents **always** and ~ represents **not** (LTL formula)

Is it correct?

Can I represent '->' (i.e. implication) with **Until** operator in LTL?

I searched on the internet on "LTL to Buchi Automata". Sadly, I didn't understand. Can somebody please explain it to me Step by Step in layman's term?

Is there a simpler way to depict an NBA for P and complement of P?

I will be grateful. Thank you very much :)

Update: following the reply, I have few more doubts:

If the property P can be written as G(w1 -> F c1), then as per this article on  [LTL model checking translation From LTL to Buchi automata](https://www.dis.uniroma1.it/~degiacom/didattica/metodiformali/aa2008-09/materiale/6-modelchecking/slide6-ltl-model-checking-2up.pdf) (Page 26), the Buchi automata can be drawn as:

[G(w1 -> F c1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0CN0.jpg)

I don't know why it is different from the one given in the book (example 4.30)

I know, it is really unnecessary to use LTL here, and probably I am making things complicated, but I want to know how to depict an NBA from the (any) given property. Like you mentioned Ayrat, LTL does not have the operator ->, since it is a Boolean operator, I cannot use the method "LTL to Buchi automata" given in "Constructing Automata From Temporal Logics Formulas: Tutorial" (or can I?)

What is the correct way to construct such NBAs?

Thank you

Comment: looks like homework... your property in LTL is: `G(w1 -> F c1)` (note `G` in front). As for drawing, 1) first, do it as you can (trial-error...), 2) once you get acquainted with Buchi and LTL, you may try to search online tools for that (spot library, GOAL library, ltl2ba, etc.). As for algorithms: Wolper's paper "Constructing Automata From Temporal Logics Formulas: Tutorial" may help (it explains a very simple algorithm, although not efficient)

Comment: @Ayrat: Thanks for your help :) It's not my homework. I am trying to solve the exercises given in "Principles of Model Checking" book. It's on Page 227, after the chapter 4. I was wondering if I should use the LTL formula here, since LTL is Chapter 5. Is there any simpler way to draw an NBA for the given property? Also, Can I represent '->' (i.e. implication) with Until operator in LTL?

Comment: example 4.30 in that book (version 2007037603) shows the automaton exactly for property `P`. `->` is logical operator not the temporal operator (see for example http://www.testoutofcollegeclasses.com/clep-exam/27/Implications.html). `U` is the temporal operator, while `->` is the Boolean operator. LTL _does_ have the operator `->`. I guess there is no _need_ to use LTL for that exercise...

Comment: @Ayrat: thanks for the response. Could you please see the answer (I wanted to include the image) below and answer my query? (I hope you know the answer) I am going crazy because of this NBA. It's important for my exam :'( and I don't want to by heart some diagram for the property mentioned in the book. I want to know the procedure so that I can construct an NBA from any property

Comment: @Riya208 The aim of the exercise in the book is to force you to understand what exactly the semantics of LTL are and what Buchi automata do. Once you fully understood both, you should be able to draw the automaton down without a complex analysis. If you can't do that yet, then you did not develop an intuition for Buchi automata yet. Note that the image that you added to the question is *not* the automaton for G(w1 -> F c1). There is an error in it, and to test your current understanding, you should try to fix it. Hint: The word $\{w1,c1\}\emptyset^\omega$ should be accepted by the automaton.